# Is there any way to tell a if backup is complete?

Tags: backup, filesystems, restore, comparison

I lost a disk. It's clicking, which seems to be something almost everyone agrees is not very fixable.

I have backups.  Problem is, I look at the backups and the first thing I think is "Is that all I had on them?  I thought I had more."

The drive was mounted in Ubuntu, permanently, as `/home/home`. Not that it matters, but mostly it had backups.

Is there anyway to tell from the system itself whether I had anything on that disk that is not part of the backups?  (Which I can restore, but I have not as yet). That is, is there some log or something that would tell me something about the files that I had on that disk and confirm for me that there weren't directories/files on the mount point that were not backed up?

Comment: You could possibly look to see what the most recently dated file is. That would let you know roughly when the last backup was made.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I have the backups, so I know when the backups were run. What I don't know is whether all the directories were actually set ti be backed up. I think they were, but now that I can't read the disk, I don't know. I now wonder whether I left some directories not backed up.

Comment: what method was used to backup?  some tools /apps do have retrievable logs.